# SCCM2012 SQL Query has an error

Tags: sql, sccm

I am creating an SQL query for my SCCM collection but I get that there is an error. It doesn't tell me what the error is and the rule looks ok for me.

```
Select SMS_R_SYSTEM.ResourceID,SMS_R_SYSTEM.ResourceType,SMS_R_SYSTEM.Name,SMS_R_SYSTEM.SMSUniqueIdentifier,SMS_R_SYSTEM.ResourceDomainORWorkgroup,SMS_R_SYSTEM.Client, SMS_R_User.UniqueUserName
FROM SMS_R_System
JOIN SMS_UserMachineRelationship ON SMS_R_System.Name=SMS_UserMachineRelationship.MachineResourceName
JOIN SMS_R_User ON SMS_UserMachineRelationship.UniqueUserName=SMS_R_User.UniqueUserName
Where SMS_R_User.UniqueUserName in (select UniqueUserName from SMS_R_User where UserGroupName = "Domain\\GroupName")
```

Comment: Have you tried running this query in SSMS to see if it reports an error?

Comment: Just guessing but maybe `"Domain\\GroupName"` should be `'Domain\\GroupName'` ? Double-quotes are normally used as quoted identifiers for objects while single-quotes denote string literals.

Comment: Also, please start using table aliases for this kind of query, it really improves readability

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you haven't misspelled any column names the only thing that I can see that would throw an error is that maybe `"Domain\\GroupName"` should be `'Domain\\GroupName'`? Double-quotes are normally used as quoted identifiers for objects while single-quotes denote string literals.

With the double quotes you would probably get an error like:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line ?? Invalid column name
>   'Domain\GroupName'.

Also, the subquery in the where clause looks unnecessary, this query should be equivalent (if I'm not misreading it):

```
SELECT 
    S.ResourceID,
    S.ResourceType,
    S.Name,
    S.SMSUniqueIdentifier,
    S.ResourceDomainORWorkgroup,
    S.Client, 
    U.UniqueUserName
FROM SMS_R_System S
JOIN SMS_UserMachineRelationship UMR ON S.Name = UMR.MachineResourceName
JOIN SMS_R_User U ON UMR.UniqueUserName = U.UniqueUserName
WHERE U.UserGroupName = 'Domain\\GroupName'
```

Comment: So this will give me a list of devices whose primary user belongs in the AD Security Group "GroupName"?

Comment: I would think so yes, but I don't know your database scheme or application so I can't say for sure. Give it a try and see if you get the expected results.

Comment: i tried it and got syntax error. Unfortunately SCCM12 doesn't tell you where the error is located like in SQL Server.

Comment: I have no knowledge about SSCM, but maybe you can test the query directly in the SQL Server